# getting radio , check box in prototype?

Tags: prototypejs

how can i get the checkbox, radio button, pulldown menu values using id with using form in prototype js?

Answer (score 2):

See [`$F`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-F/)

**Edit**
`$F` get's the *text value* of an element by it's ID. For example if you had a drop down select box called "month" you could use `$F('month')` to get it's value "February".

In response to your follow up question, "how can i get the count of number of check box is selected" use this:

```
$$('input:checked').length
```

Comment: can you explain this further im not getting using this

Comment: can i use $F to get the selected radio button value

Comment: @clockworkgeek : how can i get the count of number of check box is selected ? in prototype js

Comment: can u elobrate how can  i get value of check box and pull down using $F

Comment: how to get the selected check box and it length in prototype ?...anyone help

Comment: im having multiple check boxes

Comment: $$('input:checked').length
 im having two sets of check box in my form im distiguish by name having same name for a set 0of check box, how can i find the value and length in that case

Comment: If the names of a set are all "set1" then use `$$('input[name="set1"]:checked').length`

Comment: @clockworkgreek : thank u, and how can i take individual value fro check box

Comment: @clockworkgreek : length worked for me wonderfully, help me in retrieving value too. thanks a lot in advance

Comment: The `$$` function returns an array of elements, to get just an array of their values use `$$('input[name="set1"]:checked').pluck('value')`

Comment: @clockworkgreek :finally, i got as comma seperated value, how can i get individual value on each iteration , please help

Comment: It's an array of values so you can treat it like any other [array](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/). `...pluck('value')[0]` is the first value, `...pluck('value')[1]` is the second and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`$F` returns the value of a form field.

Given

```
<input id="field1" name="field1" value="foo">
```

This is true:

```
$F('field1') == 'foo'
```

Given

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox1" id="mycheckbox1" value="ABC" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox2" id="mycheckbox2" value="DEF"/>
```

This is true:

```
$F('mycheckbox1') == "ABC"
$F('mycheckbox2') == null
```

Comment: does it return the value of a check box ? how can i get the individual value

Comment: Yes. I edited above and added another example regarding checkboxes.